# In Android, the MediaPlayer creation fails to work. Same code has worked for me for months

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to create a MediaPlayer in a very simple way:

```
 mRingtonePlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, mRingtoneUri);
```

Where, using logging, I can confirm that `mRingtoneUri` is: `content://media/external/audio/media/1620`

This is a file I've used numerous times for testing. When I attempt to run the code above, I get the following error:

```
01-13 11:33:21.108: ERROR/MediaPlayer(20685): message received msg=200, ext1=1, ext2=26
01-13 11:33:21.108: ERROR/MediaPlayer(20685): callback application
01-13 11:33:21.108: ERROR/MediaPlayer(20685): back from callback
01-13 11:33:21.108: ERROR/PlayerDriver(2197): Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info -17
01-13 11:33:21.108: ERROR/MediaPlayer(20685): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-17
01-13 11:33:21.108: ERROR/MediaPlayer(20685): SISO TEST MEDIA_ERROR
01-13 11:33:21.108: ERROR/MediaPlayer(20685): error (1, -17)
01-13 11:33:21.108: ERROR/MediaPlayer(20685): callback application
01-13 11:33:21.108: ERROR/MediaPlayer(20685): back from callback
```

Again, this one line has worked for me for months. I am even using the same files that I did before, and the content uri is being generated.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Restarting the phone (twice) fixed the issue, but it still can happen intermittently on my device. Troublesome, but not a programming error per say.